# How to use tsconfig.json in babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, babel-cli

I'm building a script that compiles Monorepo packages, I'm using typescript, each package has its own typescript config.

I want to tell `@babel/preset-typescript` which config file to use.